# Updating session in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

So I'm using hibernate to get number of rows from my database in a list :

```
public class FlightDAOImpl implements FlightDAO {

    private Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Flight> listFlight() {
        List<Flight> list = new ArrayList<>();
        session.beginTransaction();
        list = session.createQuery("FROM Flight WHERE Flight_Origin = :origin_id OR Flight_Destination = :destination_id")
                .setParameter("origin_id", App.airport.getAirportId())
                .setParameter("destination_id", App.airport.getAirportId())
                .list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return list;
    }
}
```

It works, but I if I update some data in the table(from like sql developer) the session will not update I will get the same data the next time I call listFlight().
I can use this instead :

```
public List<Flight> listFlight() {        
    List<Flight> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    list = s.createQuery("FROM Flight WHERE Flight_Origin = :origin_id OR Flight_Destination = :destination_id")
    .setParameter("origin_id", App.airport.getAirportId())
    .setParameter("destination_id", App.airport.getAirportId())
    .list();
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    return list;      
}
```

but that will require me to close the session and open it every time when call listFlight(). Is there a way to force update on the whole session data whithout closing and reopening it? I'm kind of newbie, so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: use getCurrentSession() instead of openSession().

Comment: @Sachin Verma thank you very much, it's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @SachinVerma can you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use getCurrentSession() instead of openSession().